# android-security ... How do I fix this jquery security alert: "Your app contains one or more libraries with known security issues"

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, android-security

In my Play Developer console I see the following message for an updated android app I have in my store:

Vulnerable Libraries
Your app contains one or more libraries with known security issues. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.

JavaScript jquery 1.9.1 SNYK-npm:jquery:20110606
SNYK-npm:jquery:20150627
SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006 assets/helix/vendor/jquery.js

Please how can I solve this error?

Comment: Switch to an updated version of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/), currently it's at 1.11.0

Comment: Please how do I update the jQuery version?